# Mongoose validation value from another table

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

> This is my Product table schema

```
let schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    price: {type: Number, required: true},
    description: {type: String, required: true},
    sizes: {type: Object, required: true},
    offer: {type: Number, default: 0},
    images: {type: Array, required: true},
    deal: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    category: {
        _id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true},
        name: {type: String, required: true}
    },
    company_name: {type: String, required: true}
});
```

> What I am trying to do

I am trying to validate if `category.name` value equal exist in my another table called `Category`.

Answer (score 2):

You *could* use an async validator and query the categories collection.  Something like this (using promise sytax for validator):

```
let schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {type: String, required: true},
  price: {type: Number, required: true},
  description: {type: String, required: true},
  sizes: {type: Object, required: true},
  offer: {type: Number, default: 0},
  images: {type: Array, required: true},
  deal: {type: Boolean, default: false},
  category: {
      _id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true},
      name: {
        type: String, 
        required: true,

        validate: function(nameVal) {
          return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            let Category = mongoose.model('Category');  //you would have to be sure that Category model is loaded before this one.  One reason not to do this        
            Category.findOne({name: nameVal}, (err, cat) => resolve(cat ? true : false));  //any non null value means the category was in the categories collection
          });
        }

      }
  },
  company_name: {type: String, required: true}
});
```

Some thoughts about this:

1. This is documented at http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#async-custom-validators.
2. As it states there, the validator is *not* run by default on updates.  There are a lot of caveats to read through there.
3. In my experience with NoSQL DBs, the code creating a new Product would take care to make sure the category being assigned was valid.  The code probably found the category from the DB at some point prior. So having a validator lookup would be redundant. But you may have a situation where you have a lot of code that creates Products and want validation in one place.
4. When I see that you are storing a document of {_id: ..., name: ...} as the category field in your Product schema, I think you might want this instead:

   ```
   ...
   category: {Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Category'},
   ```

   This allows you to store a reference to a category you have retrieved from the categories collection.  *Mongoose will load up the category document inline for you* when you retrieve the products, if you use the populate method on your query.  See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html.  There are a lot of options with the populate functionality you might find useful.  It does *not* do validation that the category is valid on save, as far as I know.  But if you take this approach, you would have already looked up the category previously in the code before your save (see the link to get a better idea what I mean).  Essentially this gives you join like behavior with MongoDB, with the storage savings and other benefits one expects from "normalization".